# Find PDF Form Field position

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, pdftk

I realize this question has been asked a lot, but I could not find any information about how to do this in RoR. I am filling a PDF with form text fields using [pdf-forms](https://github.com/jkraemer/pdf-forms) but this does not support adding images, and I need to be able to add an image of a customer's signature into the PDF. I have used [prawn](https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn) to render the image on the existing PDF, but I need to know the exact location to add the image on the signature line. So my question is how can I look at an arbitrary PDF and find the exact position of the "Signature" form field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using [pdf2json](https://github.com/modesty/pdf2json) to find the x,y position of the form field. I generate a JSON file of the original pdf using this command:

```
%x{ pdf2json -f "#{form_path}" }
```

The JSON file is generated in the same directory as `form_path`. I find the field I want using these commands:

```
jsonObj = JSON.parse(File.read(json_path))
signature_fields = jsonObj["formImage"]["Pages"].first["Fields"].find_all do |f|
    f["id"]["Id"] == 'signature'
end
```

I can use [prawn](https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn) to first create a new PDF with the image. Then using [pdf-forms](https://github.com/jkraemer/pdf-forms), I `multistamp` the image pdf onto the original PDF that I want to add the image to. But multistamp `applies each page of the stamp PDF to the corresponding page of the input PDF` so make sure your image PDF has the correct number of pages or else your image will get stamped on every page. I only want the image stamped onto the first page, so I do the following:

```
  num_pages = %x{ #{Rails.configuration.pdftk_path} #{form_path} dump_data | grep "NumberOfPages" | cut -d":" -f2 }.to_i
  signaturePDF = "/tmp/signature.pdf"
  Prawn::Document.generate(signaturePDF) do
    signature_fields.each do |field|
      image Rails.root.join("signature.png"), at: [field["x"], field["y"]], 
                                                  width: 50
    end
    [0...num_pages - 1].each{|p| start_new_page }
  end

  outputPDF = "/tmp/output.pdf"
  pdftk.multistamp originalPDF, signaturePDF, outputPDF
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this gem 'wicked_pdf. You just write html, and this gem automatically convert it to pdf 
Read more https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf

Comment: This doesn't work because I am not generating the PDF from HTML. I am taking an existing PDF (that was uploaded), and I want to add an image to the correct form field.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pure ruby implementation that will return the field's name, page, x, y, height, and width using Origami https://github.com/gdelugre/origami

```
require "origami"

def pdf_field_metadata(file_path)
  pdf = Origami::PDF.read file_path

  field_to_page = {}
  pdf.pages.each_with_index do |page, page_index|
    (page.Annots || []).each do |annot|
      field_to_page[annot.refno] = page_index
    end
  end

  field_metas = []
  pdf.fields.each do |field|
    field_metas << {
      name: field.T,
      page_index: field_to_page[field.no],
      x: field.Rect[0].to_f,
      y: field.Rect[1].to_f,
      h: field.Rect[3].to_f - field.Rect[1],
      w: field.Rect[2].to_f - field.Rect[0]
    }
  end

  field_metas
end

pdf_field_metadata "<path to pdf>"
```

I haven't tested it particularly thoroughly but the snippet can hopefully get you most of the way there.

Also -- keep in mind the above coordinates calculated are in points from the bottom left of the pdf page rather than the top right (and are not in pixels). I believe there's always 72 points per inch, and you can get the total page points by calling `page.MediaBox` in the `pdf.pages` loop above. If you're looking for pixel coordinates, you need to know the DPI of the resulting rendered document.